# Should I use an anchor or input tag in a navigation bar?

Tags: html

I don't know what I should use in my nav bar:

```
<li><a></a></li>
```

or

```
<li><input></li>
```

In all tutorials it is `<a>` but why? In the nav bar I have a link to the next page and this solution is correct? But what if a button in the nav-bar opens a popup window? In this situation should I use `<input>` or `<a>`?

Comment: Why would you use `<input>` in a navigation bar? [Input](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) is a tag that allows people to write text in a box. Unless you want, for example, a search bar in your navigation, I don't see a practical use for using `<input>`.

Comment: Well you could just use them for what they are for `a` tags for links and `<input type="button">` for buttons. It's not like you must use strictly all of one or the other for your nav bar, but this is more opinion based.

Comment: @ZacWebb I'm assuming OP means `<input type="button">`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek true. But still seems unnecessary unless there is a form involved somewhere in the navigation bar.

Comment: Yes input type button. Exist any standard for nav bar ? For links I should use a for buttons input ?

Comment: @ZacWebb It seems like the OP wants a button in the second case *"But what if button in nav-ba"*, and is wondering if they should use a button or an `a` tag. In that case it would make sense to use a button instead of have an `a` tag simulate the functionality of a button and prevent it's default action.

Comment: @Kewin For the most part yes, although you could still use `a` and treat them like buttons. It would make more sense to just use a button (`<input type="button">`) instead of having `a` act like a button. Neither way is necessarily wrong for nav bars, as such the *"correct"* one is more of a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Kewin is this "popup window" an actual page or a modal window?

Answer (score 0):

As a general practice, use `input` elements to accept data from the user. For page links, use the `a` tag.

Quote from MDN:

> The HTML  element is used to create interactive controls for
>   web-based forms in order to accept data from the user.

Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: This doesn't really answer what the OP is looking for.